# Convert spread sheet to excel using App script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I'm trying to send a spreadsheet file as Excel via mail. The mail is sent successfully but the file can't be opened due to incorrect format (I need an xlsx file.)

The code I used is below.

```
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder_id')
  var files  = folders.getFiles();
  
  if (files.hasNext()) 
  {

    file = files.next();
      
      url = file.getUrl();
      var params = {
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
       };

     
      var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
      blob.setContentType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL).setName(fileName + ".xlsx");
            
    MailApp.sendEmail(email_ids, 'Sample Subject', 'Mail with attachment', {
    attachments: [blob],
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
    cc:email_id
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually that code didnt work at  my side.I got the same kind of file from the code. So I coverted the spreadsheet to CSV using some codes.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
url = file.getUrl();
```

with

```
url = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getUrl().replace(/edit$/, 'export?format=xlsx')
```